# Collectionview contentSize wrong

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I'm currently developing an app using `UICollectionView`. I need to know the height of the contentSize, which I'm doing by

```
self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height
```

Now this is working, but the returned value is not correct for portrait mode always. What should I do to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just get self.collectonView.contentSize in viewDidAppear and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     NSLog(@"%0.0f-%0.0f",self.collectionView.contentSize.width,self.collectionView.contentSize.height);
}

-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    NSLog(@"%0.0f-%0.0f",self.collectionView.contentSize.width,self.collectionView.contentSize.height);
}
```